# Update HTML Table Row Data with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I've spent the best part of an hour reading various docs - some of which I have interpreted at 'it can't be done' and others suggesting it can.

I have a straighforward HTML table which is initially populated.  Within each row, I'd like an 'update' link that fires off a webservice query and returns updated data relevant to that row.

Now, I know I can use .load to update a specific 'item' (i.e the price), however I need to be able to return a few bits - last update, status etc.

I've got so far with this, and the code I have (below) works to the degree that it returns the data - but not in the correct place, and not formatted (which, if my last hour of research is correct, is because .load can't return html).

My question is - is there a way to simply modify what I have to make this work, or is there a better way of achieving it?  At the moment, the 'external' file processes the web service request, updates the database and then returns the data from the database.

In theory, I could fire off multiple .load requests, but I would have to either query the webservice multiple times (inefficient) or delay some elements so they get the 'post webservice' data.  I'm sure there must be a better way though!

Existing code below...

```
<!--- The Table --->
<tbody>
<div id="prices">
<cfoutput query="getprices">
<tr>
    <td>#merchant_name#</td>
    <td>#price#</td>
    <td><a href="#deeplink#">Link</a></td>
    <td>#last_checked,Now())#</td>
    <td>#updateflag#</td>
    <td><a href="##" onclick="$('#prices').load('/tasks/prices_update.cfm?pid=#getproduct.ID#');">Update</a></td>
</tr>
</cfoutput>
</div>
</tbody>
```

Comment: you can disabled the button for couple of seconds if you wish.

Comment: What sort of data does the web service return, and in what format? Ideally it would return plain, unformatted data, so it is tangible for use in whatever environment you need to use it.

Comment: @Utkanos - I can have it return in any format, I'm stuck for what to do with it though.  At the moment it returns the same (updated) row in HTML format.  I can output it in plain text instead though, I'm simply unsure of how I can pass it back into the 'front end' table.

Comment: Looks like you need to do a little more client side processing than just `onclick`.  If you expect the web server to give something to the page after the AJAX request completes, you're going to need more JavaScript code to put it in the user interface (the page) in a way the viewer can understand.  `$('#prices').load(...)` doesn't achieve much, other than sending an AJAX request.

Comment: Well the question of what data format the web service returns is crucial to how you then take that data and update the view with it. Perhaps your web service returns JSON data? You can post an example of what the AJAX response is? And yes, as Kevin628 says, you should avoid inline events (e.g. `onClick`) and handle these things separately, in a dedicated JS file, rather than in amongst your HTML.

Comment: @Utkanos - It's a slightly complete scenario in as much as the page first queries the Db row to see which web service to use, queries the webservice + updates the database, then queries the database to get the updated data.  As the updated output data is coming from my local database, I can output it in any way.

Comment: @kevin628 - Thank you, thats what I was worried may be the case - I'm still finding my feet with JS/jQuery

Comment: Let me put it another way: what is the result of visiting `/tasks/prices_update.cfm?pid=#getproduct.ID#`? In other words, what is the response returned to your jQuery `load()` request?

Comment: @Utkanos - currently, it returns exactly the same HTML as my code above, but with updated data.